# EC2 instance ssh connection not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, fstab

I tried to connect to my EC2 Ubuntu LTS instance but I failed. 
The error message I got like below: 
    ssh: connect to host ec2-79-125-83-13.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

I checked the instance log, the last lines like below:

```
The disk drive for /dev/xvdf is not ready yet or not present. 
Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

What could be the problem here?

Could you help me please?

Comment: Your instance isn't booting up because it's failing to mount that device. This is probably a mismatch between what the image expects and the actual EC2 instance configuration. Which AMI are you using?

Comment: ubuntu/images/ebs/ubuntu-precise-12.04-amd64-server-20130124

Comment: That doesn't really help. What's the AMI ID, and where did you get it from?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS. It's EC2's standart AMI.

Comment: To identify the origin of the problem : In _console.aws_ with a right click on the instance > _"Instance Settings"_ > _"Get System log"_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably an `/etc/fstab` issue. Ubuntu is trying to mount a partition present in `/etc/fstab` and yet not able to find that partition i.e. /dev/xvdf.

In order to troubleshoot this, you need to -

1) shutdown this instance

2) Launch another instance

3) Attach the root EBS of this instance to the new instance from step(2)

4) mount the EBS from step(3) , say in /mnt/ebs

5) Check `fstab` for any inconsistency , /mnt/ebs/etc/fstab. If there is any inconsistency, backup that file, modify it, unmount the partition, and re-attach it to the instance in step(1) and launch it.

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly as you said. For me it was to add ```nofail , nobootwait``` arguments at the failling line in ```/etc/fstab```.

Comment: That page was also a great help in the process: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html (particularly the command ```lsblk``` to check volume are attached and mounted correctly)

Answer (score -2):

Things to check:

1. Verify your Security Group rules allow SSH access from your source
   IP address.
2. Verify if IPtables is running and blocking connections.
       You can either `service iptables stop` or add a rule to your input
       chain to allow access

If the above doesn't help, run `ssh@yourhost -v` to gather more details and paste it here so we can see where the disconnect is happening. Connection refused is generally a firewalls access control issue. Hope this helps

Comment: EC2's security groups drop packets, not reject so it's not that. There's no console access either so iptables can't be checked.

Comment: If you login into EC2 there is console access from a java session.

Comment: there is a rule which give access to port 22. ssh -v gives same error: Connection refused

Comment: @OvidioBorrero, There is a problem with java. It's not working for a while :(

Comment: @RomeNYRR clearly a wrong answer, you may want to delete it to avoid confussion and recover your karma!